# Error while running program in Android Titanium

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am new to Appcelerator Titanium.

I have downloaded Appcelerator Studio and its prerequisites (Oracle JDK and Node.js) and also installed all the needed android SDKs.

[image: Image showing all sdks are installed]

When I try to run Favebook project from Titanium documentation (Creating your first Titanium App) using titanium_1_WVGA800, I always get an error:

> ```
> [ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "titanium_1_WVGA800"
> For help, run: titanium help build
> 2016-01-29T11:50:34.771Z | TRACE | titanium exited with exit code 1
> 2016-01-29T11:50:34.771Z | ERROR | Error: ti run exited with error code 1
>     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
>     (C:\Users\Pragnesh\.appcelerator\install\5.1.0\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\plugins\run.js:92:66)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
> 2016-01-29T11:50:34.787Z | TRACE | Sending exit signal to titanium process:  23888
> [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
> ```

Need help to find out what error is this.

Comment: Have you tried  titanium help build?

Comment: @MarkChorley No.. Where can i find this?

Comment: Just run it on the command line, at least that's what the error message is saying - "For help, run: titanium help build"

Comment: I have both Titanium sdk and cli installed. Yes, I tried it on CLI it is showing me -
`[ERROR] Unable to find any emulators`
Now I am looking why they are not able to find my standard ARM android emulator.